# How to delete an item from Listview by position?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, listviewitem

Is there any way to delete items from `listView` by knowing only the position? and is it a property of the `listview` or the `adapter`? please see the image below, which demonstrates the available properties of the `ListView`

[image]

***Updat_1***

The problem still persists. I populate the `Listview` with data retrieved from `SQlite DataBase`. The data retrieved is returned in an `Array` from `String[] retrieveMPLNames()`, then I convert this `Array` into `ArrayList` then bind the `ArrayList` to the `ArrayAdapter`. When I want to delete, First, I delete the item from the `SQlite DataBase` then go through the same procedure again, which is, calling `String[] retrieveMPLNames()` which will retrieve the available data from the `SQlite DataBase` and the returned `Array` will be converted into `ArrayList` then bind it to the `ArrayAdapter`. But, the item is never deleted from the `ListView`. Please see the Code below.

***Java_Code:***

```
if (isDBEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "@onCreate(): The DataBase Is Empty");
    }else {
        Log.i(TAG, "@onCreate(): The DataBase Is Not Empty");

        bindArrayListToArrayAdapter(arrayToArrayList(retrieveMPLNames()));
    ....
    ....
protected void deleteItemFromDataBase(int itemClickedPos) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG, "@deleteItemFromDataBase():");
    if(! sqliteDB.isOpen()) {
        //mplOpenHelperDB = new MPLDataBase(getApplicationContext());
        sqliteDB = mplOpenHelperDB.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.i(TAG, "@deleteItemFromDataBase(): The Database was closed And Now It Is Opened");
    }
    String locName = mplOpenHelperDB.getLocationName((itemClickedPos+1));
    int []x = mplOpenHelperDB.getIDs();
    Log.i(TAG, "@deleteItemFromDataBase(): total rows in the database = "+mplOpenHelperDB.getCurrentRowNumber());
    Log.i(TAG, "@deleteItemFromDataBase(): name to delete from database = "+locName);
    Log.i(TAG, "@deleteItemFromDataBase(): ID of the item to delete from the database= "+x[itemClickedPos+1]);

    mplOpenHelperDB.deleteRow((itemClickedPos+1));
    Log.i(TAG, "@deleteItemFromDataBase(): total rows in the database after delete = "+mplOpenHelperDB.getCurrentRowNumber());

    notifyArrayAdapter();
}

private void notifyArrayAdapter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG, "@notifyArrayAdapter(): ");
    mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.savedlocationlist_layout, 
            R.id.savedLocationName, arrayToArrayList(retrieveMPLNames()));
    mListView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
    mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
private String [] retrieveMPLNames() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "@retrieveMPLNames(): Retrieving MPLNames");

    if (! sqliteDB.isOpen()) { 
        Log.d(TAG, "@retrieveMPLNames(): Your DataBase Was Closed And It Will Be Opened Now");
        sqliteDB = mplOpenHelperDB.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "@retrieveMPLNames(): Your DataBase Is Opened");
    int []dbIDs = mplOpenHelperDB.getIDs();

    String []str = new String[dbIDs.length];
        for(int i=0; i<dbIDs.length; i++) {
            str[i] = mplOpenHelperDB.getLocationName(dbIDs[i]);
            Log.d(TAG, "@retrieveMPLNames(): "+str[i]);
            Log.d(TAG, "@retrieveMPLNames(): Total Rows Retrieved = "+str.length);
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: yes, just remove the item from the list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the item from the underlying data i.e. array, cursor, whatever it is and then update the ListView to reflect the change.

Comment: Your ArrayAdapter is supplying data to the ListView. When you want to delete something from the ListView you first need to delete it from the array. Following that you need to tell the LisView that the array has changed by calling MArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove an item from your `ListView` (named `listview`), when the user clicks that particular item, do the following:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
    final int positionToRemove = position;
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            listview.remove(positionToRemove);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }});
    }
});
```

Comment: please see the available properties of my listview in the image

Comment: @Elpharaoh what is the name of the `ArrayList` you are using to set your `listview`?

Comment: i dont have an `ArrayList` i have an `Array` populated from retrieved records from database